# Issues in substituting API in English with API in other language using i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, i18next

I have used i18next in my project to have it in two language. The problem I encountered is that It doesn't work for APIs that I fetch in my project.

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [faqData, setFaqData] = useState([]);
   
const apiUrl = t("apiUrl");

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setFaqData(data.data[index]));
}, []);

  const index = 0;
```

Also I have set it on i18next component as follows:

```
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      apiUrl: "http://..../api/V1/homepage/faqs_english",
    },
  },
  fa: {
    translation: {
      apiUrl: "http://..../api/V1/homepage/faqs_persian",
    },
  },
};
```

The problem is that it shows English API data for both language. I would be so thankful if you help me solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe this is an off-topic comment, but I would keep i18n as close to the user-facing application as possible, and definitely keep it off of any API/programming-level support. This simplifies the design of the underlying API, allowing the UI (and only the UI) to worry about conveying proper results.